# Python Desktop Application - Packaging

Tags: python-3.x, desktop-application

I have build my first desktop application using PyQT5, Python3.7 and Sqlite3 on Mac. I am creating .exe using pyinstaller for windows platform (I have moved my code to windows as Wine on Mac is not working correctly and tired of VMs).

After I moved my code when I tried to run the app on Windows, it crashed because of no tables the sqlite3 database. This would happen with the .exe  as well.

I can write a utility function to check if all the tables exists before app starts and create if tables do not exist like below.

```
def tables_exist():
    dbc = create_connection().cursor()
    dbc.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
    res = dbc.fetchall()
    tables = {r[0] for r in res}

    if len(TABLES_SET^tables) == 0: # TABLES_SET is a set of all the table names
        return True
    else:
        try:
            scriptFile = open(DB_DEFINATION, 'r')
            script = scriptFile.read()
            scriptFile.close()
            dbc.executescript(script)
            dbc.connection.commit()
            print('Table Created')
            return True
        except:
            print("Something went wrong:")
            return False
        finally:
            dbc.close()
```

Call above method in my app.py:

```
 def db_check(self):
    if tables_exist():
        return True
    else:
        show_maessage_box(self, message='Could not create tables.')
        print('Backend no supported!')
        return False

 app =QApplication(sys.argv)
 main = Main() # This is a custom class containing main PyQt Dialogbox
 if db_check():
    main.show()
    app.exec()
 else:
    print('Something went wrong')
```

Not sure if that is the correct way. I am very new to desktop application development. Looking for the right approach for the problem.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @EricJin added the code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to post your code with your question. It helps us to answer the questions better.

To put code in the question include it in ``` and ````.

Edit -  I could not add a comment as I dont have 50 reputations as yet so sorry for that.